# Cleaning up Ruby code

Tags: ruby

I am writing a parser and throughout my code in various methods I have code very similar to this:

```
    if @sym.type == TokenType::IDENT_TOKEN
      next_token()
      if @sym.type == TokenType::EQUALS_TOKEN
        next_token()
        if @sym.type == TokenType::NUMERAL_TOKEN
          next_token()
          const_a(keys | ConstList.follow)
        else
          error(keys | ConstA.first)
        end
      else
        error(keys | ConstA.first)
      end
    else
      error(keys | ConstA.first)
    end
```

This is hard to read in my opinion and looks very cluttered, it is not idiomatic Ruby code at all. Is there some way that I could condense this down and make it less cluttered?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These questions belong on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could collapse all of the `error` method calls into one call by doing a `next` or `return` after the successful parse and then falling through to a single error.

I think also that you should just accept a certain amount of code explosion when writing a recursive descent parser. That's just kind of what they look like.

You could `include` some constant-definition modules to get rid of the scope qualifiers.

Comment: I am not in a loop above, so what would happen if I called `next`?

Comment: But you could put a loop in just so `next` would work, or make a method so `return` would work. You could also return `true` from `next_token` so you could string the tests together with `&&`. You could leave out the `()`. You could define a method that tests against a token value and calls `next_token` if the test succeeds. But really, I don't think your code is that bad. RD parsers are a bit verbose.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably be able to clean this up immensely if you applied the state machine pattern. Not only would it be easier to read, but you could produce a diagram of the flow through your parser with the right tools.

That's how tools like [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) build parsers.

Comment: It would be nice to use the pattern you mention, but this is for an assignment and has some strict parameters for what can and can't be used as a solution. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd try and invent the "I Can't Believe It's Not a State Machine" pattern and use that instead.